Nest.js microservices with TCP transporter
I was reading microservices section in the nest.js documentation. As doc mentions, there are two ways to transmit messages with transporters: 1-request-response and 2-event-based

Most transporters natively support both request-response and event-based message styles.

My questions are:

Does TCP transport support event-based messages? Is there any implementation like a simple message queue on the memory?
If it does not, does nest.js just treat event-based messages like request-response messaging when using TCP transporter?

